# How to find Twitter accounts of a certain category that have a certain range of followers?

Tags: twitter

I want to find all the Twitter accounts that tweet about a certain category (let's say, cars) and that have a certain range of followers (let's say, from 1000 to 3000).

Is there any tool that can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [followerwonk](https://followerwonk.com/bio) to do that type of search.

Type `cars` into the search field, click on "more options", then type `1000` into the "Min followers" field and `3000` into the "Max followers" field.  Then click the "Do it" button.  It will return a [sortable list](https://followerwonk.com/bio/?q=cars&q_type=all&flmin=1000&flmax=3000) of all Twitter profiles with "cars" or "car" in the name or description, and between 1000 and 3000 followers.

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.